# Can hosted web UWP apps specify their URI bounds at runtime?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm planning on developing a UWP client for the open-source messaging platform [Mattermost](https://about.mattermost.com/) primarily to extend platform support to Windows 10 Mobile, with the intention of eventually adding first-class features such as native notifications, an unread message indicator on the live tile, Cortana integration, and so on. I've started work on a [proof-of-concept](https://github.com/Stack-in-a-box/MattermostUWP) which works well given a predefined URL to be loaded from at launch but I'd like to give the ability to users to specify a Mattermost server URL at runtime the way the Electron-based [desktop client](https://github.com/mattermost/desktop) does.

The problem arises in the fact that hosted web apps require you to define application content URI rules ([ACURs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/hwa-access-features)) at compile time that limit the scope of URIs the app is allowed to load from for security reasons – if a link to a URL outside the scope of the rules is accessed then it'll be loaded in the device's default browser rather than the UWP application context, which is obviously not what I'm going for here.

So, my question can be expanded to the following three:

1. *Is it possible to define these URI bounds at runtime* so that a user can specify an arbitrary server URL within the UI (possibly by delegating from one application which modifies the necessary configuration and then launches another)?
2. If not, *can the URI rules be bypassed to allow loading from an arbitrary URL* and then I could handle verifying the existence of a valid server instance myself at runtime instead?
3. If so, *would bypassing the URI rules stop me from being able to access Windows Runtime APIs* which would be necessary for implementing features like native notifications?

So far I've tried using wildcards to allow any URI but Visual Studio complains that the ACUR values are invalid (probably rightly so, but frustrating all the same), i.e.:

- `https://*`
- `https://*/*`

Failing all this, is there some alternative UWP-based solution that's less restrictive than hosted web apps that might be worth me exploring instead?

Comment: You can use html 5 /JS to create apps for UWP

Comment: Thanks, @KenTucker, but I don't see how that answers my question.